# Is there a way to perform addition/subtraction with HashMap values in Java among Integer objects?

Tags: java

```
    public static HashMap makeHashMap() {
        HashMap<String, Integer> table = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        table.put("C", 1);
        table.put("V", 2);
        table.put("D", 3);
        table.put("W", 4);
        table.put("E", 5);
        table.put("F", 6);
        table.put("X", 7);
        table.put("G", 8);
        table.put("Y", 9);
        table.put("A", 10);
        table.put("Z", 11);
        table.put("B", 12);
        // System.out.print(table);

        return table;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Object> makeArrayList(HashMap<String, Integer> table) {
        Object[] keys = table.keySet().toArray();
        ArrayList<Object> randomlyGeneratedNotes = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
            Object key = keys[new Random().nextInt(keys.length)];
            //  System.out.println(key + " " + table.get(key));
            randomlyGeneratedNotes.add(key);
        }
        System.out.println(randomlyGeneratedNotes);
        return randomlyGeneratedNotes;
    }

    public static void pitchMovement(ArrayList<Object> randomlyGeneratedNotes, HashMap table) {
      Iterator<String> keySetIterator = table.keySet().iterator();
        String key = keySetIterator.next();
        int first = table.get(key);

        for (Object o : randomlyGeneratedNotes) {
            //you want to grab the values of 2 neighboring keys
            if (table.containsKey(o)) {
              //  System.out.println("true");
                Object firstNote=  table.get(key);
                System.out.println(firstNote);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I perform addition/subtraction between my HashMap values? Or did I use an inappropriate data structure? I tried doing something my `pitchMovement` method, but the `int first = table.get(key);` line gives an error of incompatible types:

> Object cannot be converted to int.

Not sure if this is a simple error or a more complex one.

Comment: You are actually storing an Integer object in the HashMap and not int.  You can only store objects in the HashMap.  You can cast it or convert to int by using intValue() function

Comment: Don't return a raw `HashMap`! Change `HashMap makeHashMap()` to `HashMap<String, Integer> makeHashMap()`

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to encourage you to put some learning effort into understanding generics and interfaces.  Java will be friendly in its conversion between primitives and value types (like `int` and `Integer`), but plays dumb when dealing with objects of type `Object`.  The problem you're encountering in multiple places is that you're needlessly letting your strongly typed values degrade to type `Object`.

I'd suggest the following changes:

Change `public static HashMap makeHashMap()` to `public static HashMap<String,Integer>`.  Otherwise, you'll get back the equivalent of `HashMap<Object,Object>`, which you don't want.

In `public static ArrayList<Object> makeArrayList(HashMap<String, Integer> table)`, you're extracting the `String` typed keys from HashMap, and then converting them to type `Object` when building your array.  Don't change their type-- keep them as String.  You may have been thrown by "toArray()" converting to an array of `Object` values.  You can use this technique to preserve the type:

```
    String[] keys=new String[table.size()];
    keys=table.keySet().toArray(keys);
```

In doing so, you can easily change the signature of `makeArrayList` to return an ArrayList of type `String`:

```
  public static ArrayList<String> makeArrayList(HashMap<String, Integer> table)
```

Your pitchMovement signature could be changed to:

```
  public static void pitchMovement(ArrayList<String> randomlyGeneratedNotes,
                                   HashMap<String,Integer> table)
```

Note that the specific error you encountered related to `HashMap table` being defined without generic parameters (which is equivalent to `HashMap<Object,Object>`).

When your types haven't been reduced to `Object`, then Java will use "auto-boxing" to automatically convert between your `int` and `Integer` types as needed.  The following, for example, is valid.

```
    Integer x=new Integer(5);
    int y=10+x;
    Integer z=x+y;
```

In sum, math operations will work as you'd expect without you having to cast and convert between primitives and their equivalent value types, no matter where you store them, but you must take efforts to keep those types preserved wherever you use them.

Comment: Thanks so much for the time and energy you put in the answer. I have applied your changes and handling everything just got way easier. I thought I was getting messy.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
Integer first = table.get(key);

as table is a map of String and Integer, you can get the value as Integer.
You can then convert your Integer variable to int.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I've tried this and I get "Object cannot be converted to Integer". Just tried casting: int x = (Integer) number; and that seems to work for now. Not sure why I had to do that though- why it wasn't an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your method signature with generic parameters:

```
public static void pitchMovement(ArrayList<Object> randomlyGeneratedNotes, HashMap<String, Integer> table)
```